# Setting field in child popup

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I'm trying to create a html page with some javascript. The javascript opens a child popup and tries to fill in one of the fields in that page. This is the code I've got:

```
//creates a new popUp
function openRequestedPopup(url,name,top,left) {
return window.open(url, name, "width=640, height=640"+", top="+top+", left="+left);
}

//setting field in child popup
function setTextInputField(popUp,id,text){
var el=popUp.document.getElementById(id);
el.setRangeText(text);
}

x=openRequestedPopup("https://www.facebook.com/","1",0,0);
setTextInputField(x,"email","lalalalala");
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
code: 18
message: "Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame."
name: "SecurityError"
stack: "Error: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.↵         at Error (native)↵    at <anonymous>:2:10↵    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:668:39)↵    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:607:52)↵    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:519:21)"
__proto__: DOMException
```

I understand that not everybody should be allowed to get elements from other pages. But I don't understand why I'm not allowed to get that element since it is my child page/popUp. Is there a workarround for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider all of the sensitive data that you can view on facebook when you are logged in. Now imagine you are currently logged in to facebook by your current session, and you go to some random website which opens up a pop up to facebook - and has complete access and control of that pop up window. They can now do anything with your facebook account and any data in it. This is why there is cross-origin security in browsers.

Comment: hmmm I see, So I can't log on to facebook using javascript and a popup?

Comment: No I wouldn't think so I'm afraid

Comment: :(, do you know if it is possible to have one parent page and multiple child popups. WIth each popup logged in to a different facebook account? (so when I log in to popup 1, I can still login in popup 2 with different credentials)

Comment: The issue with that would be that you would need each pop up window to have a different session with facebook, which would require a different cookie in each window. Since the scope of cookies is browser wide (with the exception of things like 'incognito' mode in chrome, though you wouldn't be able to tell chrome to open a new window in incognito from JS), this would not be possible.

Comment: hmmm.... All I want is a program where I can sign in with multiple facebookaccounts and each facebook account should visit the links I provide in a textfile. Can this be done with java? Which language is the best for something like that?